# Cannot get authorization to

Tags: google-apps-script

I keep getting the following error when I run a Google apps script:

`Execution failed: You do not have permission to call getFoldersByName`

Here is the line of code I'm running:

```
var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Mission Response');
```

When I run the script from Script editor it runs without any problems. However, I never get the authorization dialog (the one that authorizes DriveApp). When I run the script from inside the spreadsheet, the script fails with the execution error above.

Comment: what do you mean by "I run the script from inside the spreadsheet"

Comment: When the script editor is closed and the script is run using the custom menu item associated with it (the script is contained within the spreadsheet). Eventually got the authorization dialog and it's working now.

Comment: I have the same Issue! When I call the function directly, it works, but when I trigger it from an OnEdit event, it logs the same error.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of struggle, I found the solution on [this link](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4414).

It states that you **cannot use** services that require **authentication** with **simple triggers**, like `onEdit()`.

Knowing that, I did this to solve it:

I had something like:

```
function onEdit(){
  var folder = DriveApp.gefFoldersByName('My Folder Name').next();
  doSomething(folder);
  ...
}
```

Then I created the installable trigger:

```
function onEditTrigger(){
  var folder = DriveApp.gefFoldersByName('My Folder Name').next();
  doSomething(folder);
  ...
}
```

[image]

I hope it helps, as it took me a lot of time to figure out.